# Spring File Upload with RequestParam

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

According to the standard way of file uploading in spring: https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/
we shall use @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file to receive the file uploaded from the form.

But I wonder why the annotation is "RequestParam" rather than something like "RequestBody", since in the form we specify "method=post", shouldn't the data be inside form post body?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To get `MultipartFile` in spring we either use `@RequestPart` or `@RequestParam`. These annotations are used to associate the part of a `multipart/form-data` request.This is written in spring docs:

> public @interface RequestPart
>
> Annotation that can be used to associate the part of a
>   "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument. Supported method
>   argument types include MultipartFile in conjunction with Spring's
>   MultipartResolver abstraction, javax.servlet.http.Part in conjunction
>   with Servlet 3.0 multipart requests, or otherwise for any other method
>   argument, the content of the part is passed through an
>   HttpMessageConverter taking into consideration the 'Content-Type'
>   header of the request part. **This is analogous to what @RequestBody
>   does to resolve an argument based on the content of a non-multipart
>   regular request.**
>
> **Note that @RequestParam annotation can also be used to associate the
>   part of a "multipart/form-data" request with a method argument
>   supporting the same method argument types.**
>
> The main difference is that when the method argument is not a String,
>   @RequestParam relies on type conversion via a registered Converter or
>   PropertyEditor while @RequestPart relies on HttpMessageConverters
>   taking into consideration the 'Content-Type' header of the request
>   part. @RequestParam is likely to be used with name-value form fields
>   while @RequestPart is likely to be used with parts containing more
>   complex content (e.g. JSON, XML).

link:https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestPart.html

Comment: I see! Thanks a lot!